# How to Solve this Exception

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a Todo Application in Flutter with taking SQFLITE as Database.
I am adding a "Category" Property to my Tasks to Group them.
When importing Values of Categories stored in database and showing it in my add a task
view, I am using a dropdownmenubutton and all the categories are being shown as dropdownmenu Item.
The code is below

```
var _categories = <DropdownMenuItem>[];
_loadCategories() async {
var _categoryService = CategoryService();
var categories = await _categoryService.readCategories();
categories.forEach((category) {
  setState(() {
    _categories.add(DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text(category['Name']),
      value: category['name'],
    ));
  });
});
```

}

And the Code to Show these categories is

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
                value: _selectedValue,
                items: _categories,
                hint: Text("Category"),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedValue = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
```

And the Error Message is this

---

Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'.

Tried to infer 'dynamic' for 'T' which doesn't work:
Parameter 'onChanged' declared as     'void Function(T?)?'
but argument is 'void Function(Object?)'.
The type 'dynamic' was inferred from:
Parameter 'value' declared as     'T?'
but argument is 'dynamic'.
Parameter 'items' declared as     'List<DropdownMenuItem>?'
but argument is 'List<DropdownMenuItem>'.

Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.

---

Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you please provide code how is your _selectedValue declared?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add type of Value

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String?>()
```

and also

```
var _categories = <DropdownMenuItem<String?>>[];
```